# SQL - Aggregate column based on filters

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

My data has an ID, date, and points_earned field. Each row represents the points earned by the ID for that date.

I want to create something similar to this:

**ID** | **Points_Earned_January** | **Points_Earned_February** | **Points_Earned_March**

The result should be `GROUP BY` ID. Points_Earned_January should give a `SUM` of all the points_earned that fall in January for that ID.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       (case when date >= '2020-02-01' and date < '2020-03-01' then points else 0 end) as points_feb,
       (case when date >= '2020-03-01' and date < '2020-04-01' then points else 0 end) as points_mar
from t
group by id;
```